# Python - how to accumulate comma using a for loop

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, accumulator

community - this is my first post, so please forgive me if I failed to properly display this message. I am trying to add commas as depicted below in the test cases. It appears there are more efficient ways than what I have coded below; however, I would like to solve the problem using my code below. What in the world am I missing?

```
def get_country_codes(prices):
    country_prices = prices
    p = ""
    for i in country_prices:
        if i.isalpha() and i == ",": 
            p = p + i[0] + ","
    return (p)
```

My code is returning:

```
Test Failed: expected NZ, KR, DK but got 
Test Failed: expected US, AU, JP but got 
Test Failed: expected AU, NG, MX, BG, ES but got 
Test Failed: expected CA but got 

from test import testEqual

testEqual(get_country_codes("NZ$300, KR$1200, DK$5"), "NZ, KR, DK")
testEqual(get_country_codes("US$40, AU$89, JP$200"), "US, AU, JP")
testEqual(get_country_codes("AU$23, NG$900, MX$200, BG$790, ES$2"), "AU, NG, MX, BG, ES")
testEqual(get_country_codes("CA$40"), "CA")
```

Comment: You realise that `i.isalpha() and i == ','` can never be true as `','.isalpha()` is false, right? So your code isn't really a case of being "more efficient" - it's checking your logic actually works :)

Comment: Anyway - just use `re.findall(r'\b(\w+)\$\d+', prices)`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better to accept a `list` instead of a `string` type as a parameter for `get_country_codes`. This will prevent you from having to worry about parsing the string and ignoring the comma. I'd recommend [Joining Lists and Splitting Strings by diveintopython.net](http://www.diveintopython.net/native_data_types/joining_lists.html).

This code accepts a list, iterates through it, splits each value on the `$`, grabs the first token, and checks if this passes `isalpha()`. If it does, it appends the returned list.

```
def get_country_codes(prices):
    """Get country codes given a list of prices.

    :param prices: list of prices
    :return: list of alphabetical country codes
    """
    countries = []
    for price in prices:
        country = price.split('$')[0]
        if country.isalpha():
            countries.append(country)
    return countries

# As a proof, this line will concatenate the returned country codes
# with a comma and a space:
print(', '.join(get_country_codes(["NZ$300", "KR$1200", "DK$5"])))
# As another proof, if your input has to be a string:
print(get_country_codes("US$40, AU$89, JP$200".split(", ")))
print(get_country_codes(["AU$23", "NG$900", "MX$200", "BG$790", "ES$2"]))
print(get_country_codes(["CA$40"]))
```

The code returns

```
NZ, KR, DK
['US', 'AU', 'JP']
['AU', 'NG', 'MX', 'BG', 'ES']
['CA']
```

Finally, to make an assertion:

```
testEqual(get_country_codes(["NZ$300", "KR$1200", "DK$5"]), ["NZ", "KR", "DK"])
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining the joining and split functions. I ultimately opted to add or statements to my if statement. Thanks a bunch!!!

Answer (score 0):

Using your code ... 
For every character check if is allowed.
Include "," and space in the allowed characters.

```
def get_country_codes(prices):
    country_prices = prices
    p = ""
    for i in country_prices:
        if i.isalpha() or i == "," or i == " ": 
            p = p + i[0]
    return (p)
```

Comment: Thank you. This is ultimately how I ended up fixing it.